# How to make an armour stand's name invisible through walls?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make a secret room with invisible armour stands with text, but I don't want the armour stand names to be visible from outside the room. 
I thought of a way to fix it, but using a radius command on the armour stand to make it visible when a player is near doesn't work with multiplayer; a player outside of the range would be able to see the armour stand name if someone else is in range.
How can I fix it so the name is only visible through air, not blocks?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: @Frank I've tried to, but all I can find is bugs on JIRA and plugin websites (and a CS:GO page... I did type Minecraft in!) I'm sorry I am not able to give a well-researched question, it is not really possible with the info I can find.

Comment: @Frank To me it looks like he tried a visible and an invisible armour stand. What else should he try? Another entity? Would do the same. A sneaking player? Obviously not a good solution.

Comment: The solution is to use a renamed helmet, but I can't write a proper answer with the full command, because I can't access my PC. Can someone else, please?

Comment: Probably can use scoreboards teams to change the visibility of the name, just add the player to the team when in the room and remove them when they leave.

Comment: @ModDL I've already got teams, but I'm going to try to do my best to get a system that'll reset the team of the player when leaving the area. Should do the trick, and I'll also add an automatic system on a timer so if someone teleports, it still resets it. Thanks!

Comment: Since nobody answered, I tried to do it myself. Turns out, names of helmets on armour stands or not visible. I think they used to at some point, but that isn't the case anymore. Therefore I have now undeleted my answer that I had self-deleted previously.

Answer (score 1):

## You can't.

Seems like you have already tried everything that I would try. There's no other way, names are always visible through walls.

The best other option might be to have a renamed item in an item frame. That will only be visible when looking at the item frame, which requires an unobstructed line of sight.